# Flowchart + Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Would like to include PRISMA flowchart in my study and I might need help on setting up my tikzpicture commands. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What did you try until now? I presume you already looked for `flow chart` in TeX.SX and I'm sure you found a lot of information. So, what's your particular question?

Answer (score 14):

Here is a possible solution using the tikz `positioning` and `chains` libraries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
        draw, rectangle, align=center, text width=5cm, font=\small, inner sep=3ex},
    mylabel/.style={
        draw, rectangle, align=center, rounded corners, font=\small\bf, inner sep=2ex, 
        fill=cyan!30, minimum height=3.8cm},
    arrow/.style={
        very thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1.5cm,
    start chain=1 going below,
    every join/.style=arrow,
    ]
    % the chain in the center going below
    \coordinate[on chain=1] (tc);
    \node[mynode, on chain=1] (n2)
        {\# of records after duplicates removed};
    \node[mynode, join, on chain=1] (n3)
        {\# of records screened};
    \node[mynode, join, on chain=1] (n4)
        {\# of full-text articles accessed for eligbility};
    \node[mynode, join, on chain=1] (n5)
        {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
    \node[mynode, join, on chain=1] (n6)
        {\# of studies included in quantitative sysntesis\\ (meta-analysis)};

    % the branches to the right
    \begin{scope}[start chain=going right]
        \chainin (n3);
        \node[mynode, join, on chain]
            {\# of records excluded};
        \chainin (n4);
        \node[mynode, join, on chain]
            {\# of full-text articles excluded, with reasons};
    \end{scope}

    % the nodes at the top  
    \node[mynode, left=1cm of tc, anchor=south east] (n1l)
        {\# of records is identified through database searching};
    \node[mynode, right=1cm of tc, anchor=south west] (n1r) 
        {\# of additional records indentified\\ through other sources};

    \coordinate (n2nl) at ([xshift=-2cm]n2.north);
    \coordinate (n2nr) at ([xshift= 2cm]n2.north);
    \draw[arrow] (n1l.south -| n2nl) -- (n2nl);
    \draw[arrow] (n1r.south -| n2nr) -- (n2nr);

    % the labels on the left
    \begin{scope}[start chain=going below, xshift=-8cm, node distance=.8cm]
        \node[mylabel, on chain] {\rotatebox{90}{Identification}};
        \node[mylabel, on chain] {\rotatebox{90}{Screening}};
        \node[mylabel, on chain] {\rotatebox{90}{Eligibility}};
        \node[mylabel, on chain] {\rotatebox{90}{Included}};
    \end{scope}

    % the title
    \node[above=2.5cm of tc, font=\bf] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Slightly modified (simplyfied) @Sergej solution:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=15mm and 10mm,
    start chain=going below,
 mynode/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, text width=5cm,
        font=\small, inner sep=3ex, outer sep=0pt,
        on chain},
mylabel/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, rounded corners, 
        font=\small\bfseries, inner sep=2ex, outer sep=0pt,
        fill=cyan!30, minimum height=38mm,
        on chain},
every join/.style = arrow,
     arrow/.style = {very thick,-stealth}
                    ] 
\coordinate (tc);
% the title
\node[above=of tc,font=\bfseries] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};
% the nodes at the top
\node (n1a) [mynode, left=of tc]    {\# of records is identified 
                                        through database searching};
\node (n1b) [mynode,right=of tc]    {\# of additional records indentified\\
                                        through other sources};
    % the chain in the center
\node (n2)  [mynode, below=of tc]   {\# of records after duplicates removed};
\node (n3)  [mynode,join]   {\# of additional records indentified\\
                                        through other sources};
\node (n4)  [mynode,join]   {\# of full-text articles accessed 
                                            for eligibility};
\node (n5)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
\node (n6)  [mynode,join]   {\# of studies included in quantitative syntesis\\
                                (meta-analysis)};
% the branches to the right
\node (n3r) [mynode,right=of n3]    {\# of records excluded};
\node (n4r) [mynode,right=of n4]    {\# of full-text articles excluded,
                                        with reasons};
% lines not included in join                                        
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=+22mm] n1a.south) coordinate (a)
                                       -- (a |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-22mm] n1b.south) coordinate (b)
                                       -- (b |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] (n3) -- (n3r);
\draw[arrow] (n4) -- (n4r);
% the labels on the left
    \begin{scope}[node distance=7mm]
\node[mylabel,below left=-3mm and 11mm of n1a.north west]
                {\rotatebox{90}{Identification}};
\node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Screening}};
\node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Eligibility}};
\node[mylabel]  {\rotatebox{90}{Included}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Scaling above image is not straightforward, since design and positioning of labels in blue boxes are accommodated to sizes of the used `noded distance` and height of nodes.

This can dependency can be a bit reduced by the following code changes (in code are marked by `<--`)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                calc, 
                chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 10mm,
    start chain=going below,
 mynode/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, 
        minimum height=\mh,             % <---
        text width=5cm,
        font=\small, outer sep=0pt},
ml/.style args = {#1/#2}{
        draw, rectangle, align=center, rounded corners,
        font=\small\bfseries, inner sep=2ex, outer sep=0pt,
        fill=cyan!30,
        minimum height=1.6*\mh,     % <---
        left=11mm of #2},
every join/.style = arrow,
     arrow/.style = {very thick,-stealth}
                    ]
\def\mh{12ex}                       % <---
\coordinate (tc);
% the nodes at the top
\node (n1a) [mynode, left=of tc]    {\# of records is identified
                                        through database searching};
\node (n1b) [mynode,right=of tc]    {\# of additional records indentified\\
                                        through other sources};
% the title
\node[above=of tc |- n1a.north,font=\bfseries] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};  % <---
% the chain in the center
    \begin{scope}[nodes={mynode,on chain, join}]
\node (n2)  [below=of tc |- n1a.south]                                      % <--- 
            {\# of records after duplicates removed};
\node (n3)  {\# of additional records indentified\\
             through other sources};
\node (n4)  {\# of full-text articles accessed
             for eligibility};
\node (n5)  {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
\node (n6)  {\# of studies included in quantitative sysntesis\\
             (meta-analysis)};
    \end{scope}
% the branches to the right
\node (n3r) [mynode,right=of n3]    {\# of records excluded};
\node (n4r) [mynode,right=of n4]    {\# of full-text articles excluded,
                                        with reasons};
% lines not included in join
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=+22mm] n1a.south) coordinate (a)
                                       -- (a |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-22mm] n1b.south) coordinate (b)
                                       -- (b |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] (n3) -- (n3r);
\draw[arrow] (n4) -- (n4r);
% the labels on the left
\node[ml=1.5*11ex/n1a.west] {\rotatebox{90}{Identification}};               % <---
\node[ml=28mm/n1a.west|- {$(n2)!0.5!(n3)$}] {\rotatebox{90}{Screening}};    % <---
\node[ml=28mm/n1a.west|- {$(n4)!0.5!(n5)$}] {\rotatebox{90}{Eligibility}};  % <---
\node[ml=1.5*11ex/n1a.west|- n6] {\rotatebox{90}{Included}};                % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that someone is interested for flowchart without labels on the left, that MWE can be quite simplified:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 10mm,
    start chain=going below,
 mynode/.style = {
        draw, rectangle, align=center, 
        minimum height=\mh,             % <---
        text width=5cm,
        font=\small, outer sep=0pt},
every join/.style = arrow,
     arrow/.style = {very thick,-stealth}
                    ]
\def\mh{9ex}                            % <---
\coordinate (tc);
% the nodes at the top
\node (n1a) [mynode, left=of tc]    {\# of records is identified
                                        through database searching};
\node (n1b) [mynode,right=of tc]    {\# of additional records indentified\\
                                        through other sources};
% the title
\node[above=of tc |- n1a.north,font=\bfseries] {PRISMA 2009 Flow Diagram};  % <---
% the chain in the center
    \begin{scope}[nodes={mynode,on chain, join}]
\node (n2)  [below=of tc |- n1a.south]                                      % <--- 
            {\# of records after duplicates removed};
\node (n3)  {\# of additional records indentified\\
             through other sources};
\node (n4)  {\# of full-text articles accessed
             for eligibility};
\node (n5)  {\# of studies included in qualitative synthesis};
\node (n6)  {\# of studies included in quantitative sysntesis\\
             (meta-analysis)};
    \end{scope}
% the branches to the right
\node (n3r) [mynode,right=of n3]    {\# of records excluded};
\node (n4r) [mynode,right=of n4]    {\# of full-text articles excluded,
                                        with reasons};
% lines not included in join
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=+22mm] n1a.south) coordinate (a)
                                       -- (a |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-22mm] n1b.south) coordinate (b)
                                       -- (b |- n2.north);
\draw[arrow] (n3) -- (n3r);
\draw[arrow] (n4) -- (n4r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko, have  a blessed day

Comment: Both solutions look complicated for me. ;) What is simplified in the second one?

Comment: Good question (regarding differences between answers)! As far as I now see, `on chain` is not repeated in each node in chain. Maybe is in it some more small differences (as stated in answer). If you will read TikZ manual, you will see, that both answers are relatively simple, and in MWE are comments, which explains, to which part of images particular fragment of code belongs. Of course, you can draw this flowchart more directly, without used capabilities of TikZ libraries, which are used in both answers. Consequently code will not be so concise as presented here.

Comment: I got a bit deeper on both answers here. I don't like them. ;) To much explicite positioning using `mm` and things like that. I would like to make it more _relative_ and flexible. E.g. The PRISMA-nodes should _know themselfs_ to which of the blue-nodes in the left they belong to.

Comment: I think about using `matrix` but then I am not able to use `chains`. Other ideas?

Comment: @buhtz, if you not liked answers, just ignore them. Your assertion, that in both answer are to much explicit positioning, is not true. All nodes are (except the stating one) positioned relative to them. Also the most distances (in my answer is only one exception) is defined by `node distance`, which is preset. I wish you luck in searching for better solution. Probably would be good idea to ask a new question with new requirements, for solution parameters (use of matrix, ...). As far as I now estimate (over thumb)  both answer, it will difficult to make simpler and more clear solution.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289896/horizontal-fixing-of-tikz-nodes

Comment: I will checkyour new question  in evening.